# ArangoDB: How to export collection to CSV?

Tags: csv, arangodb

I have noticed there is a feature in web interface of ArangoDB which allows users to Download or Upload data as JSON file. However, I find nothing similar for CSV exporting. How can an existing Arango DB collection be exported to a .csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export data from ArangoDB to CSV, then you should use [**Arangoexport**](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangoexport/). It is included in the full packages as well as the client-only packages. You find it next to the `arangod` server executable.

Basic usage:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangoexport/examples/#export-csv

Also see the CSV example with AQL query:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangoexport/examples/#export-via-aql-query

Using an AQL query for a CSV export allows you to transform the data if desired, e.g. to concatenate an array to a string or unpack nested objects. If you don't do that, then the JSON serialization of arrays/objects will be exported (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Thanks. That's better than my answer and I'll use this going forward. It's good to see an active community around Arango here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default Arango install includes the following file:

```
/usr/share/arangodb3/js/contrib/CSV_export/CSVexport.js
```

It includes this comment:

```
// This is a generic CSV exporter for collections.
//
// Usage: Run with arangosh like this:
//   arangosh --javascript.execute <CollName> [ <Field1> <Field2> ... ]
```

Unfortunately, at least in my experience, that usage tip is **incorrect**. Arango team, if you are reading this, please correct the file or correct my understanding.

Here's how I got it to work:

```
arangosh --javascript.execute "/usr/share/arangodb3/js/contrib/CSV_export/CSVexport.js" "<CollectionName>"
Please specify a password:
```

Then it sends the CSV data to stdout. (If you with to send it to a file, you have to deal with the password prompt in some way.)